# VirtualEnv: Creating virtual environment fails in Win 7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Just got python, pip and virtualenv installed on my windows 7 box.

Ran into the following issues when I want to create a virtual enviroment:

**virtualenv test** gives me:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
-c run on 09/18/14 00:24:25

Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Downloading/unpacking setuptools

Cleaning up...

Removing temporary dir C:\Users\Han\test\build...

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 209, in find_requirement
    file_locations, url_locations = self._sort_locations(locations)

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 128, in _sort_locations
    sort_path(os.path.join(path, item))

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 109, in sort_path
    if mimetypes.guess_type(url, strict=False)[0] == 'text/html':

File "c:\python27\Lib\mimetypes.py", line 287, in guess_type
    init()

File "c:\python27\Lib\mimetypes.py", line 348, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()

File "c:\python27\Lib\mimetypes.py", line 256, in read_windows_registry
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

any ideas? Have tried using the registry checker as well as hard coding the mimetypes.py file: http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/ but the same error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a different specific error message from the `read_windows_registry()` function than the one I talked about in [my blog post](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/), so I don't think deleting/skipping corrupted registry keys containing null characters is going to work for you.

I just found [issue #505](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/505) in the *virtualenv* project which seems to be talking about your specific problem. There are several recommendations in that thread - do any of those solve your problem? It looks like the problem was subsequently fixed by [pull request #579](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/579) anyway, so perhaps you just need to update to a newer version of *virtualenv*?